# Hidden character in SQL column value in oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, replace, trim

I have a value in column of a table and somehow there is some hidden character at the end of the string. I cannot see it or remove it. The string is placed below. The total characters that I can see in this string is 25, but I when check the length of the string it is showing as 26. I tried TRIM function but thinking it could be a space, but it is not. How to remove this kind of characters from string in oracle query. Actually, I am using regexp_replace to replace some part of this string, but because of this issue the regex not able to match the last number in the string to replace everything before it.

28/110/41492/171486/98122

Here is my regex function

```
regexp_replace(trim(ATTRIBUTE_VALUE), '(^|.*?/)' || '98122' || '(/|$)', 'replaced' || '\2', 1, 1)
```

Comment: You can look at the char codes with `select dump(attribute_value) from ...`.

Comment: This is what I can see there:  Typ=1 Len=26: 50,56,47,49,49,48,47,52,49,52,57,50,47,49,55,49,52,56,54,47,57,56,49,50,50,2

Comment: Yes, `\x02` = Start of Text (STX) is at the end. You may replace `(/|$)` with `'(/|[^[:print:]]*$)'` and that char will be matched and captured into Group 2.

Comment: The fourties and fifties are ASCII codes for the digits. The 2 is not. So it's the last character. You can remove it thus: `update mytable set attribute_value = substr(attribute_value, 1, 25) where ...`.

Comment: the 2 means last character?? How was it entered to the column value? Can I use this substr inside regex_replace? I need to do it on the fly during an update query.

Comment: You may replace `(/|$)` with `'(/|[^[:print:]]*$)'` and that char will be matched and captured into Group 2.

Comment: No, 2 does not mean "last character", but as you can see the 2 is the last number, so it's the last character that has the code 2. You can remove it with a simple `substr` as already shown, or independent from its position   with `regexp_replace(attribute_value, '[^[:print:]]')`.

Comment: I really want to deal with such kind of rows and remove veered characters in it before replace, so that my actual regex_replace would work.

Comment: what exactly is that 2 mean?

Comment: `DUMP` shows you the character codes the system stores for your string. You can look up the codes in an ASCII table. 50 means '2', 56 means '8', 47 means '/' and so on. 2 is a code for a non-printable character.

Comment: oh...non printable character!! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in two steps:

1. remove all non-printable characters
2. apply your replace pattern

This is:

```
regexp_replace
(
  regexp_replace(attribute_value, '[^[:print:]]'), -- printable string
  '(^|.*?/)' || '98122' || '(/|$)', -- search pattern
  'replaced' || '\2',  -- replace pattern
  1, -- position
  1 -- occurrence
)
```